# Jacobi fields are invariant under local isometries

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm currently learning Jacobi fields, and I'm stuck on proving the following proposition in Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds* (Proposition 10.5, exercise):

Let $(M,g)$ and $(\tilde M, \tilde g)$ be differentiable manifolds, and $\varphi : M \to \tilde M$ be a local isometry. Let $I = [a,b] \subset \mathbb R$, $\tilde I = [\tilde a, \tilde b] \subset \mathbb R$ be intervals, $\gamma : I \to M$ and $\tilde \gamma : \tilde I \to \tilde M$ be geodesics, such that $\tilde \gamma = \varphi \circ \gamma$. Furthermore, let $J$ and $\tilde J$ be vector fields along $\gamma$ and $\tilde \gamma$, respectively, related by $d\varphi_{\gamma(t)} (J(t)) = \tilde J(t)$ for all $t \in I$. Then, $J$ is a Jacobi field if and only if $\tilde J$ is.

**My attempt:** For the "if" direction, I think I need to show that the Jacobi equation holds, i.e. $\tilde J'' + R(\tilde J', \tilde \gamma')\gamma' = 0$ if $J$ is a Jacobi field. For this, I want to work with coordinates. Let $\{E_i(t)\}$ denote a parallel orthonormal frame along the geodesic $\gamma$. Then, $\gamma(t) = \gamma^i(t) E_i(t)$ for some component functions $\gamma^i(t)$, and $J(t) = J^i(t) E_i(t)$ for some component functions $J^i(t)$. Then, $\tilde J(t) = d\varphi_{\gamma^i(t) E_i(t)} (J^k(t) E_k(t))$, and $\tilde \gamma = \varphi \circ (\gamma^i(t) E_i(t))$. I can calculate $\tilde \gamma'$ by chain rule, but I don't know how to evaluate $\tilde J(t)$, which is where I'm stuck. I believe if I can calculate $\tilde J(t)$, then I can show the desired statement.

The "only if" direction, I presume, requires me to trace to steps above in reverse, but I'm currently a little puzzled by how to proceed there, as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This is straightforward if you use the definition of a Jacobi field as the variation of geodesics, since an isometry maps a  parametrized family of constant speed geodesics to a speed-preserving parameterized family geodesics.

Comment: @Deane oh, I see!! This is great, thank you! If you could, can you please post your comment as a brief response below, maybe with a 1-2 line hint, so I can "uptick"/"endorse" your response? Thank you!

Comment: OK. I posted a fairly detailed answer. I guess this might have been a homework problem, so, if  you want, you could try to take a quick glance and fill in the details yourself. Even if it wasn't a homework problem, I suggest doing this anyway with this and everything else you learn. I've always found that I learn something better if I read enough to get the gist of what's going on and then try (often unsuccessfuly) to fill in the details myself.

Comment: thank you, @Deane! this is extremely illuminating. have been learning geometry on my own with books, didn't have formal training in it ever before. and I was stuck on this question for a while. with your hints I was able to get somewhere! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the original definition of a Jacobi field as a variation of a $1$-parameter family of constant speed geodesics.

If $\gamma: I \rightarrow M$ is a constant speed geodesic, then a vector field along $\gamma$,
$$J: I \rightarrow T_*M\text{, where }J(t) \in T_{\gamma(t)}M, $$ is a Jacobi field if there exists a $1$-parameter family  of constant speed geodesics,
$$ \Gamma: (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow M$$ such that $\Gamma(0,t) = \gamma(t)$ and
$$ J(t) = \left.\partial_s\Gamma(s,t)\right|_{s=0}. $$

If $\phi: M \rightarrow \tilde{M}$ is an isometry, then $\tilde\gamma = \phi\circ\gamma$ is a constant speed geodesic, $\widetilde{\Gamma} = \phi\circ\Gamma$ is a $1$-parameter family of geodesics, and $\tilde{J} = d\phi_{\gamma(t)}J(t)$ is equal to
$$ \tilde{J}(t) = \left.\partial_s\widetilde\Gamma(s,t)\right|_{s=0}. $$
Therefore, $\tilde{J}$ is a Jacobi field along $\tilde\gamma$.